# Javascript JSON parse object, one object property undefined, throwing no errors

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have an extremely unique problem; I'm parsing a JSON string back into an array of objects after being passed from PHP via an xmlhttprequest. My web app does this repeatedly with the result of several different sqlsrv_query's but one query in particular has become very problematic: The id value is not consistent. What I mean by this is that if I output the JSON string before parsing, the id value is an int, but after JSON parsing it is undefined. The rest of the values are fine, it is only the id(which is the only int). Furthermore, after parsing, if I convert the object back into a JSON string the int value is restored. If I attempt to call the property like so 'object.prop' it returns undefined. I have checked, double checked, and triple checked that there are no typos. I have console.logged the entire array of objects(at various points throughout execution) with the same result. I could find nothing on SO, google, or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) that would explain this behavior, can you?

Here are some code snippets.

Inside the xmlhttprequest callback function:

```
var result1 = decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText);

console.log(result1); <-- * SEE OUTPUT BELOW *

if(result1.search('<br') === -1) {
    this.result = JSON.parse(result1);

} else {
    console.log(result1);
}

output:  [{"sheet_id":4054,"o_number":1,"o_description"...
```

After being parsed, the object is passed to another object:

```
if(!result) {
    //var error = new ErrorLog();
} else {
    console.log(result); <-- * SEE OUTPUT BELOW *

output: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
          0: Object
             prop1: someValue
             prop2: someOtherValue
             ...
             sheet_id: undefined
```

To keep the Trolls at bay, let me reiterate the extent to which I have tested this scenario:

The same results are produced in Chrome and IE11. I have tried performing the same query for multiple different records, but the same thing happens. The multitude of other queries(different queries) returning a mix of int's and strings do not have this problem. I have tried closing the browser and reopening in case it was some sort of strange temporary anomaly.

I've never posted on here before because I almost always find an answer to a question with some research but this is beyond my ability to resolve so I turn to the good people of SO for assistance, any solution, insight, or idea of where to look for an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your issue is that reproducible, I think you should try to reproduce it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/). It would be much easier for people to provide you with assistance.

Comment: So I took your advice and attempted reproducing the problem but could not achieve the same results, even utilizing the same classes that are used within the app so it MUST be something within the web app that I overlooked, but it is still baffling because I can see the value in the json string but not when it is parsed. I can't reproduce it outside of my development environment unfortunately so i guess I'll just have to take the question down.

Comment: Indeed it would be hard for people to help you if we cannot reproduce your issue… Wish you good luck then! :-)

Comment: Having the same problem with heavy headache already :S

Answer (score 1):

Its in a valid json format. Try parsing it using `JSON.parse()`

```
if(result1.search('<br') === -1) {
      this.result = JSON.parse(result1);

} else {
     console.log(JSON.parse(result1));
}
```

Comment: The second output is what it looks like in the console after it has been parsed. I don't get any errors on parsing.

Comment: using `json.parse()`??

Comment: this.result = JSON.parse(result1);

Comment: This is in `if()` im talking about `else`

Comment: The if() is there to catch php errors, I have them being outputted and they always start with <br so if there is a php error the else will output it to the console, the if() parses the json string into an array of objects

Comment: later, in the second code block I am outputting the parsed array of objects